# Is there any way to change MAC-address of built-in Bluetooth adapter?

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I should change MAC-address of a built-in Bluetooth adapter. Is there any way to do it in Yosemite (10.10.4)?

Please note - the question is about Bluetooth, not about Wi-Fi. `ifconfig` doesn't see Bluetooth device.

I've already tried to update my bluetooth adapter address in `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist` (Root\PANInterfaces\Item 0):

```
# turn bluetooth off
cp /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist ~/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
cp /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist ~/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist.backup
# edit ~/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist 
sudo cp ~/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
cd /Library/Preferences
sudo chown root:wheel com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
# turn bluetooth on
```

But it doesn't help.

Comment: Did you reboot after changing the entry in the plist file?

Comment: @patrix, the value is saved after reboot, but looks like it is something different - the actual value (displayed on bluetooth icon click with Option key) is still old.

Answer (score 1):

Look into [SpoofMAC on GitHub](https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC) which allows you to change ethernet, Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth addresses and interfaces. There's all the instructions to get you started, on that page.

Comment: It doesn't work with Bluetooth (at least on Mac) - please see the text about ifconfig in my question.

Comment: this is network specific and does not agnostically change BT address found in `system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType`